# Is there a simpler notation to forward a particular keyword argument to a function?

Tags: python

Sometimes I will write a function which calls another function with the same long keyword argument, as well as a bunch of unrelated arguments.

Is there a short notation for forwarding the keyword argument without repeating it twice, assuming that it must be called by keyword (because there are other keyword args for `bar` which are not used)?

Consider the following function.

```
def foo(a1, a2, a3, arg_with_very_long_name):
    # do other work
    bar(b1, b2, b3, b4, arg_with_very_long_name=arg_with_very_long_name)
```

Is there a shorter form for `arg_with_very_long_name=arg_with_very_long_name` in the call to `bar` above?

Comment: Explict is good. Excessively long names are bad - they generally make code _harder_ to read.

Answer (score 2):

There's not a perfect way to do this *better* than what you have already.  One other option is to use `**kwarg` unpacking instead:

```
def foo(a, b, c, **kwargs):
    # do stuff
    bar(aa, bb, cc, **kwargs)
```

The downside (and upside) here is that you don't immediately know what keywords are getting forwarded on to `bar`.  It makes it so that `foo` accepts any default arguments that `bar` does -- But you can't introspect what those are just by looking at `foo`.

Comment: Another option would be combine `**kwargs` with a `Signature` object (has been backported to python 2 by a non-standard lib). That would let you introspect, check args and so on. But so much overkill for just what @gnibbler says: make the var name shorter.

Answer (score 0):

If the keyword argument follows directly the positional arguments, you need not use the `kwarg=kwarg` syntax:

```
def f(a, b, c, some_ver_long_kwarg_name=None):
    print(some_very_long_kwarg_name)

f(1, 2, 3, 4) # Prints 4
```

Comment: -1 -- You can define functions with keyword *only* arguments: `def f(a, *, keyword): ...`. Also this breaks if you have two arguments with default value and you want to specify the *second* one but not the first.

Comment: @Bakuriu Which is precisely why I said **If the keyword argument follows directly the positional arguments**. In neither of your examples my assumption holds, however there are many situations when it actually does.

Comment: @Bakuriu True, but it works in other cases, and in particular, if OP has some control over the definition of `bar`, then this is a perfectly reasonable suggestion. (This answer could be improved by specifically calling out some of the other restrictions it imposes, though.)

Comment: @NikolaDimitroff Keyword (only) arguments *are* keyword arguments and they all follow positionals, hence that sentence is true in the case I described. Also, I don't see how starting an answer with `if False` implies that you can write whatever you want in that answer, avoiding downvotes.

Comment: @Bakuriu It seems you have trouble understanding the word `directly`. Let me quote [google](https://www.google.bg/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20directly&safe=off) on that: "directly - with nothing or no one in between.". In your first example, there is a `*` between the kwarg and the args. In your second, there are other kwargs *before* the kwarg in question. My point still stands since the OP is asking how to forward arguments and it highly likely that he wants to pass *all* arguments, not just several kwargs.

Comment: @NikolaDimitroff `*` *does* represent *nothing*. Or do you want to argue that in `f(a, b)` `b` doesn't directly follow `a` because there's a comma in-between? Your answer is a bad one because the OP is asking "how to handle long kwargs" and you are saying "in some circumstances you can avoid them using positionals". But the OP already knows this (as do 99.9% of the readers), hence the answer is quite useless without any reference to a more general solution that *does* show how to handle the OP situation or shows that you can't do anything to improve it.